# Fetching links, month and date from a table using Selenium Webdriver Python but getting web element has no attribute len()

Tags: html, python-3.x, web, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to fetch the links, date and month from a web page which has 3 tables and I am concerned about the date and month of the cells which has a valid link.

The website is https://mat.maharashtra.gov.in/1111/Mumbai-(2019)#

So I want to save in a dictionary the date like 07 JANUARY 2019  and the link and write to a file. But I am unable to fetch the month

'''

```
               for row in class_name.find_elements_by_tag_name("tr"):
                num_row = len(row) + 1
                for i in range(2,num_row):
                    column = row[i].find_elements_by_tag_name("td")
                    num_col = len(column)+1
                    for c in range(2,num_col):
                        if 2<c<7:
                            months = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'/html/body/form[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/table['+str(j)+']/tbody/tr[1]/th[2]/p/strong').text
                        elif 6<c<12:
                            months = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'/html/body/form[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/table['+str(j)+']/tbody/tr[1]/th[3]/p/strong').text
                        elif 11<c<17:
                            months = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'/html/body/form[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/table['+str(j)+']/tbody/tr[1]/th[4]/p/strong').text
                        elif c>16:
                            months = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'/html/body/form[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/table['+str(j)+']/tbody/tr[1]/th[5]/p/strong').text
```

'''

I tried the above but I am getting web element has no attribute len() even if I have used find_elements_by tag_name. Can any one help how to create the dictionary,

Thanks in Advance

Edit-:
I want to save the date like 07 JANUARY 2019 and the January need to be **scraped** from the head of the table so I need a way to scrape the links and the date and month (to be fetched from the head of the table)of the links

Answer (score 1):

This should give you the date and urls, and you can modify it to suit your needs:

```
import requests
import lxml.html as lh
from urllib.request import urljoin

url = 'https://mat.maharashtra.gov.in/1111/Mumbai-(2019)#'
base_url = 'https://mat.maharashtra.gov.in'

resp = requests.get(url)
doc = lh.fromstring(resp.text)

tables = doc.xpath('//table')
for table in tables:
    data = table.xpath('.//td/p/a')
    for d in data:
        link = d.attrib['href']
        if not link.startswith('http'):
            link = urljoin(base_url, link)
        date = link.split('/')[-1][:10]
        print(date, link)
```

Output:

```
07.01.2019 https://mat.maharashtra.gov.in/Site/Upload/Pdf/07.01.2019 (C).PDF
14.01.2019 https://mat.maharashtra.gov.in/Site/Upload/Pdf/14.01.2019 (C).PDF
21.01.2019 https://mat.maharashtra.gov.in/Site/Upload/Pdf/21.01.2019 (A).PDF
```

etc.

Comment: Thanks for replying.Actually I wanted January to be printed instead of 01

Comment: @A_the_kunal What do you mean? Please edit your question and add your expected output.

Comment: Jack Fleeting I have updated the post, please check it